# How to plot a line between two points in a scatter3 plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, line, scatter, scatter3d

I am using the following code for producing a scatter3 plot:

```
X = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3];
Y = [0,0,0,20,20,20,40,40,40,60,60,60,80,80,80,];
Z1 = [10,-48.7863,-73.3457, -68.3091, -142.0666,...
      12, -35.7863, -23.347, -29.3091,-141.0660,...
      13,3.2137,-10.3457,-33.3091,-128.0666]
Z2 = [2,8.2137,-2.3457, 46.6909, 12.9334,...
      10,11.2137, 19.6543,35.6909, 45.9334,...
       -1,16.2137,37.6543,50.6909,34.9334]

figure;scatter3(X,Y,Z1,'filled'); hold on;
scatter3(X,Y,Z2,'filled')
```

Which results in the following image:

[image]

What I would like to have is a vertical line between each blue and red dot.

An exemplary output could look like this:
[image]

I tried using the `line` function, however I am not sure how to build up the vector.

I tried:

```
line(X,Y,Z1) % will only connect the blue dots
line(X,Y,Z2) % will only connect the red dots


line(X,Y,Z1:Z2) % will give an error that the vectors must be the same length
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must [vertically concatenate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) your `Z1` and `Z2` data so that each column defines a [line](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html) to plot. You will also have to replicate `X` and `Y` in the same way:

```
line([X; X], [Y; Y], [Z1; Z2], 'Color', 'r');
```

And the result (added to your scatter plot):

[image]